# How can I save a structure which contains allocated memory to file?

Tags: c, struct

```
// Headers

struct Address{
  int id;
  char *name;
  char *email;
};

struct Database{
  struct Address *rows;
  int max_size;
  int max_data;
};

struct Connection{
  FILE *file;
  struct Database *db; 
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int i;
  struct Connection *conn;

  conn->file = fopen(argv[3], "w+");
  conn->db->max_size = atoi(argv[1]);
  conn->db->max_data = atoi(argv[2]);

  conn->db->rows = malloc(sizeof(struct Address) * (db->max_size));

  for(i=0; i<db->max_size; i++){
    struct Address adr = {.id = i};
    adr.name = malloc(conn->db->max_data);
    adr.email = malloc(conn->db->max_data);

    conn->db->rows[i] = addr;
  }

  /* Other CODE(s) here
   *
   *
  */
}
```

Now, according to these snipped code, how can I save **conn->db** structure to **conn->file** with all contents?
After that, I must be able to read it from file, again.

*I can't use stack type structure, because "**max_data**" and "**max_size**" are typed from user!*

Comment: Look up serialization.  Succinctly, you can't do it with a single call to `fwrite()` — you have to work out how to transfer the data in pieces, and how to read it back in pieces.  Or you need to redesign your structure so you have arrays in it rather than pointers.

Comment: You're right, but how i initialize **db->rows** arbitrary sized when i use an arrray? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You need to serialise and deserialise the total size before the actual data. That way you know the size, can setup db->rows and then fill it.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into writing to a binary file.

for writing

```
FILE *write_ptr;

write_ptr = fopen("test.bin","wb");  // w for write, b for binary
fwrite(conn->db,sizeof(conn->db),1,write_ptr); // write number of bytes determined by the structure size into a binary file
```

for reading from that file

```
FILE *read_ptr;

read_ptr = fopen("test.bin","rb");  // r for read, b for binary
fread(conn->db,sizeof(conn-db),1,ptr); // read bytes determined by size of structure form the file into the current conn->db structure
```

note that binary files cant be opened and read in paintext

Comment: Note that when the file was re-read, this would recover a pointer to the data allocated in the previous run of the program, which probably bears no resemblance to the memory allocated for the current run.  This is not adequate when the data structure contains pointers.